# FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database, recyclerviewadapter

Есть база данных, куда добавляются данные с датой и прочей информацией. Есть FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter, который берет эти данные и добавляет данные в RecyclerView сортируя список опираясь на дату. Мне нужно, чтобы в отдельный item в этом же RecyclerView была помещена дата и под ним располагались данные содержащие эту дату. Примерно как напоминания в календаре. Не знаю как сделать. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. Вы не знаете как добавить вьюху в уже имеющуюся?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как вьюху добавлять я знаю. Попробую объяснить. Есть список, допустим, задач. Они разбросаны по дням 1.03, 2.03, 3.03. Первого числа три задачи, второго одна, третьего пять. Сейчас в списке они сортируются по дате. Но мне нужно добавить вьюху, чтобы в ней отображалась дата, а под ней только те задачи, у которых совпадает дата с датой на вьюхе. При методе, который я знаю у меня над каждой задачей будет вьюха с датой. А нужно, чтобы они под одной группировались.

Comment: Ну например блок 02.03, там все задачи с этой датой, затем блок 03.03, там тоже все с этой датой, я правильно понял?

Comment: @danilshik да, правильно.